# Is there a way I can run TestNG tests against multiple interface implementations (DataSources)?

Tags: java, testng, mybatis

I'm looking for a way to run some TestNG tests against multiple `DataSource`s.  I've seen the `DataProvider` options for TestNG, but they don't quite do what I want.  I want to run some really simple tests against my MyBatis mappers, mainly to make sure I don't have any simple syntax errors, typos, etc.  Right now, I have a base test class like this:

```java
public class MapperTestBaseH2 {
    protected SqlSessionManager sessionManager;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() throws SQLException, LiquibaseUpdateException {
        JdbcDataSource h2DataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
        h2DataSource.setURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test-db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");

        sessionManager = MyBatisUtils.createSqlSessionManager(h2DataSource);
        LiquibaseUpdater.update(h2DataSource.getConnection(), LiquibaseUpdater.DEFAULT_CONTEXTS);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        sessionManager.startManagedSession();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        sessionManager.rollback();
    }
}
```

Then I create a test for each mapper:

```java
public class SequenceMapperTest extends MapperTestBaseH2 {
    private SequenceMapper sequenceMapper;

    @BeforeClass
    @Override
    public void beforeClass() throws SQLException, LiquibaseUpdateException {
        super.beforeClass();
        sequenceMapper = super.sessionManager.getMapper(SequenceMapper.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void selectBidSequenceTest() {
        sequenceMapper.selectSequence(Sequences.BID_SEQ);
    }

    @Test
    public void updateBidSequenceTest() {
        sequenceMapper.updateSequence(sequenceMapper.selectSequence(Sequences.BID_SEQ));
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is run each test class twice (or more), using a different `SqlSessionManager` each time.  I can use TestNG's `DataProvider` to run each test with multiple `SqlSessionManager`s, but then I have to start & rollback the session inside each test rather than in `@BeforeMethod`.

Is there an easy way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Are you using a DI container such as Spring?

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh No. I looked at Guice a bit, but, given that I'm working on something fairly small, it adds a lot more complexity than it takes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got this figured out after stumbling across [this post.](http://www.opengamma.com/blog/2011/04/04/converting-opengamma-junit-testng)  The trick is to use a combination of `@Factory` and `@DataProvider`.  First I created an abstract base class that manages the provider and the transactions.

```
public abstract class MyBatisTestBase {
    public abstract SqlSessionManager getSessionManager();

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        getSessionManager().startManagedSession();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        getSessionManager().rollback();
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "sql-session-manager-provider")
    public static Object[][] sqlSessionManagerProvider() throws SQLException, LiquibaseUpdateException {
        return new Object[][] {
                {createDerbySessionManager()},
                {createH2SessionManager()}
        };
    }

    private static SqlSessionManager createDerbySessionManager() throws SQLException, LiquibaseUpdateException {
        EmbeddedDataSource40 dataSource = new EmbeddedDataSource40();
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("memory:test-db");
        dataSource.setCreateDatabase("create");

        LiquibaseUtils.update(dataSource.getConnection(), LiquibaseUtils.DEFAULT_CONTEXTS);
        return MyBatisUtils.createSqlSessionManager(dataSource);
    }

    private static SqlSessionManager createH2SessionManager() throws SQLException, LiquibaseUpdateException {
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test-db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");

        LiquibaseUtils.update(dataSource.getConnection(), LiquibaseUtils.DEFAULT_CONTEXTS);
        return MyBatisUtils.createSqlSessionManager(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Then I use the `@Factory` annotation on the constructor of extending classes.  This has the effect of creating one instance of the test class per `SqlSessionManager` from my `@DataProvider`.

```
public class SequenceMapperTest extends MyBatisTestBase {
    private final SqlSessionManager sessionManager;
    private final SequenceMapper sequenceMapper;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "sql-session-manager-provider")
    public SequenceMapperTest(SqlSessionManager sessionManager) {
        this.sessionManager = sessionManager;
        this.sequenceMapper = sessionManager.getMapper(SequenceMapper.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void selectBidSequenceTest() {
        sequenceMapper.selectSequence(Sequences.BID_SEQ);
    }

    @Test
    public void updateBidSequenceTest() {
        sequenceMapper.updateSequence(sequenceMapper.selectSequence(Sequences.BID_SEQ));
    }

    @Override
    public SqlSessionManager getSessionManager() {
        return this.sessionManager;
    }
}
```

When I run my tests, two instances of the `SequenceMapperTest` get created, one for each `SqlSessionManager` that I set up in the `@DataProvider`.  So far, it seems to be working, but my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) has a bit of trouble splitting the logging output from each individual test.